# Stata - stacktrace not available

Tags: stack-trace, availability

I would like to import csv files on stata. I do not understand why it does not work, I obtained : stacktrace not available

What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

you cannot have non-ASCII characters in the STATA installation path. Up to now, Stata still requires ASCII.